# Connection lost in Addlive framework on iOS

Tags: ios

i have a problem with AddLive sdk. After i successfully establish connection between two devices, i get connection lost event with error message: Unhandled exception in TaskProcessor: Error initialising VP8 decoder

Any kind of help?

Comment: I'd suggest starting from the support page, where it can be solved more easily. Without more feedback like: platform (mobile/desktop/web) and the environment (device, OS) it's really difficult to help you. The problem is really specific.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Problem was in iOS6/7 on every device (iPhone/iPad/iPod). Fortunately i solved that problem. It was caused by some remaining OpenTok files (we used Opentok sdk in previous case).